# opencv program compiled, but it does not execute ( c++ )

Tags: c++, opencv

I found a below program in c++ on internet,

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(void) {

    // Read image in GrayScale mode
    Mat image = imread("emily.jpg", 0);

    // Save grayscale image
    imwrite("emilyGray.jpg", image);

    // To display the image
    imshow("Grayscale Image", image);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled the above program with the following,

```
g++ opencv1.cpp -o opencv1.exe -IC:\\opencv\\build\\install\\include -LC:\\opencv\\build\\install\\x64\\mingw\\lib -lopencv_calib3d452 -lopencv_core452 -lopencv_highgui452 -lopencv_imgcodecs452
```

After running opencv1.exe, theres no change, no image being created.

Note:- I am using mingw for compiling and my opencv is built with mingw and cmake.

Comment: maybe imread cannot find the file?

Comment: the file is in same directory as where the program is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I did not set the path to opencv dlls after I built opencv using mingw32-make.

After setting `C:\opencv\build\bin` to PATH variable of environment variables I could see the output.

Regards